# macOS Share Extension: NSExtensionActivationRule PDF predicate not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, share, share-extension

I am writing a Mac app with a share extension. The user can select a single pdf document, click the share button and select my extension. However, my extension is not being displayed and I think it has something to do with the `NSExtensionActivationRule` key in the *info.plst*. I am using a predicate statement to only allow my extension to show up when one PDF document is selected by the user. There is an example on how to do just that in the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1):

```
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems,
    $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments,
        $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
    ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
).@count == 1
```

It works if I set `TRUEPREDICATE` for `NSExtensionActivationRule`, but only with Preview.app.

Any ideas?

I have created a test app for this issue. You can get it [here](https://github.com/Iomegan/PDF-Share-Extension-App).

**Update:**
Apple Developer Technical Support says:

> According to the engineering team, this is a bug in Sharing Services. 
>   The item being shared by Preview and Finder is a URL to the
>   open/selected file.  Sharing Services is supposed to acquire the UTI
>   of the file referenced by the URL and register it in the extension
>   item attachment's registeredTypeIdentifiers.  This is not happening
>   for PDF files.  As a result, the only registered type identifier is
>   "public.file-url" (the UTI of URLs) which your query does not permit.

http://www.openradar.me/30184633

Comment: I have same problem on iOS platform. It works using iBooks app, but when trying to share pdf document using Google Drive my Share extension is not listed.

Comment: Did you found solution for you problem?

Comment: Nope. I will use technical support from Apple if nothing comes up soon. Will keep you updated.